# Get source code from open sourced Nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget

Due to the way open sourced softwares are published ( frequently, big changes ) I found It quite hard to find the original source code for the version I am using.

For example, this is one of the most used version for [IdentityServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/2.4.0).
Lots of classes and implementation has been changed since. So I have to

1/ find the Nuget Package version.

2/ Go to the linked GitHub (or another repo) ( if available )

3/ Go to the release and hope to find the same release equal Nuget version number

4/ Download source code at that release

5/ Integrate the downloaded project into my project

Is this the standard process or there is easier / more straight forward way that I should be doing? A tool to directly pull the correct release of that open sourced Nuget package directly in Visual Studio even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the standard process or there is easier / more straight
>   forward way that I should be doing? A tool to directly pull the
>   correct release of that open sourced Nuget package directly in Visual
>   Studio even?

**As far as I know**, this is the most standard, normal, simple way to get source code of the open sourced nuget package. And there is no such VS extension or tool to get source code directly. What you list is the only formal, standard way.

**Besides**, **the release and update of the source code is up to the author**, and in my test, the latest version `4.0.0-preview.3.23` section has been committed to [IdentityServer4 source code link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4). So you can build and debug the latest version.

Source code of all open nuget packages is published on the Github website and you can follow the [guidance](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4#about-identityserver4) which is provided by the author to build and debug the source code.

**For an example**, when you access the nuget package [IdentityServer4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/2.4.0), you can click on the **Source repository** which is on the right part of the website to access the open source code link:

[image]